# How to create vueJS countdown with animation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm looking for a plugin or a way to make vue js countdown like this:

[vue countdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UBjM.png)

**Note:** I'm converting xd to vue app.

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

you can use some base code this link and handle compatible by vuejs.

[demo code pen](https://codepen.io/azedo/pen/RaWVej)

I can't find any demo for vuejs

but also first u should create a simple animation for this reaction and then add pure code timer.
`after that u must merge CSS animation and js timer together.`

Answer (score 0):

As per the Vue functionality of countdown (for let's say 10 seconds), it works as follow:

```
<template>
   <div>{{ countdown }}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
         countdown: 10
        },
        methods: {
        countSeconds() {
                        if(this.countdown> 0) {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.countdown-= 1
                                this.countSeconds()
                            }, 500);
                        }
                    }
        },
        created() {
            this.countSeconds();
        }
    }
 </script>
```

You can also make the 10 seconds easy dynamically based on your need! Also as per the animation, feel free to use **transition**  or any other method based on your will!